# How do I add an event listener to each element in an html collection?

Tags: javascript, html, events, nodelist, htmlcollection

```
function eventAdded(i) {
  console.log(inputs[i]);
}
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-capture__input input');
for (i = 0; i <= inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i]);
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', eventAdded);
}
```

I am managing to log each `inputs[i]` to the console. `inputs[i]` exists.
But I am getting 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

How is this not defined if I can log each one to the console? 
Can someone please explain like I'm 5?

Comment: `i <= inputs.length` typo. Also, use event delegation instead, if you can

Comment: @CertainPerformance - probably not a typo, more of a lack of knowledge

Comment: can you explain what the typo is? It's a lack of knowledge. I'm winging it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @CertainPerformance said, your error is having `i <= inputs.length` instead of `i < inputs.length`.

The difference is that in the first case, you are going outside the boundaries of the array.

For example, if you have an array of 5 elements (remember arrays are 0-based):

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

When you check using `i <= inputs.length`, this is what's happening:

```
0 <= 5: true
1 <= 5: true
2 <= 5: true
3 <= 5: true
4 <= 5: true
5 <= 5: true
6 <= 5: false
```

So instead of iterating 5 times, you are iterating 6 times. The last one (`i=5`), is not within the array boundaries (its upper bound is `4`).

```js
function eventAdded(i) {
  console.log(inputs[i]);
}
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-capture__input input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i]);
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', eventAdded);
}
```